# Represent list of integers as a single integer in C++

Tags: c++, hash, key

I want to condense a list of about 100 non-negative 32-bit integers into a single integer. Ideally the resulting integer is always unique but a few relatively rare collisions is acceptable. **How can I do this?**

I'm writing a puzzle-solver. Part of my search algorithm is avoiding re-exploring puzzle states already seen. I'll use the integer generated from the list as the key into a `statesAlreadySeen` table. Currently I'm using strings as the keys. However I've seen noticeable performance improvements when going from string keys to integer keys in a `map<,>` hence I'd like to switch.

**Edit:** Thanks for the unordered map suggestions! However I'm still curious about an actual hashing function. IIRC there's a simple function involving basic bit manipulation and xoring. Would be great to see this and have some general understanding of the collision probabilities.

Comment: You need to use a [*hash function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth post as answer, it doesn't need more detail

Comment: Something like `boost::hash_range` should convey the basic idea...

Comment: @SundayMonday Have you tried sticking to `string` keys, but switching from `map` to `unordered_map` ?

Comment: One important point which should be mentioned: Given that you're not hashing over _all_ strings or _all_ lists of 32-bit integers, you should test your hash function with the data you're planning to feed it. I've had trouble with the Boost hash functions on some occasions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you need to use a hash function. Most easily accomplished with `boost::hash_range`:

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
std::size_t vectorhash(std::vector<int> f){
    size_t hash = std::size_t hash = boost::hash_range(f.begin(), f.end());
}
```

Having said that, if you don't have a real need to keep the states ordered (and I can't see why you would), I would go with us2012's solution of keeping `string` keys and switching to `unordered_map` - thus letting the container take care of the hashing.